# Как в 1С вывести наименование документа с помощью "Сообщить"?

Tags: 1с

Для примера в справочнике написал такой код:

```
ФактСредства = Справочники.ФактСредства;
Сообщить(ФактСредства.НайтиПоКоду("01МН-000048"));
```

Выводит наименование добавленного "товара", т.е. то, что мне нужно. А вот с документами так не получается, выводит пустой результат. Пробовал даже по реквизитам вывести, таким образом:

```
ФактСредства = Документы.ФактСредства;
Сообщить(ФактСредства.НайтиПоРеквизиту("СредстваОрганизации", "Техника"));
```

Все равно выводится пустой результат.
Как в 1С вывести наименование документа с помощью "Сообщить"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего что то не так с параметрами поиска, так как пустой результат обозначает что ничего не найдено.

Синтаксис **НайтиПоРеквизиту**(<Имя реквизита>, <Значение реквизита>, <Родитель>, <Владелец>)

**<Значение реквизита>** - тип данных должен быть тот же, что и у реквизита документа. У вас в примере задано "Техника" - это строковый тип. А в документе скорее всего тип реквизита справочник.

Если это так, сперва необходимо получить ссылку на элемент справочника, и затем подставлять его в процедуру.